# Client receiving wrong URL from sever

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, reactjs

I have front-end react, and back-end node. I am trying to send a signed AWS url from server to client side. The weird thing is, the server shows proper url address; it prints:

> https://*****.s3.amazonaws.com/abd160218_000.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1487035862&Signature=g6ti%2FN27Uw9O7ihThSr1G79nAmc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read

and sends back the url with:

```
res.send({signedUrl: data});
```

However, after immediately receiving the url on client-side, the url shows:

> https://******.dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abd1601…487037678&Signature=wC6iKrTeaOYHyNW5QPoTE%2FzAZ10%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read

Which is really confusing me. I am fetching the url from server with axios:

```
axios.get('/blogs/aws/getSignedAWSUrl', {
                        params: {
                            filename: el.file.name,
                            filetype: el.file.type
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (result) {
                          //AWS s3 signed url returned from server.
                          var signedUrl = result.data.signedUrl;
                          console.log("Signed URl:", signedUrl);
                          var options = {
                            headers: {
                              'Content-Type': el.file.type,
                            }
                          };
                          axios.put(signedUrl, el.file, options);
                    })
```

How can this actually happen?? I would appreciate any tips and ideas.

**Update- node.js code

```
 module.exports.getSignedAWSUrl = function(req, res){
    var {filename, filetype} = req.query;
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: aws.ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: aws.SECRET_KEY,
    });
    var bucket = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: 'mybucket',
        Key: filename,
        Expires: 60,
        ContentType: filetype,
        ACL: 'public-read',
    };

    bucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Aws Signed URL:", data);
            res.send({signedUrl: data});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show the NodeJS code please.

Comment: Hi Mark, I just added it. Thanks for looking through my question!

Comment: If you're using API Gateway could you have mapped the API to another lambda function or forgotten to press "deploy" on the latest API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out...

In my index page, I would configure my AWS to fetch data from dynamoDB. Then when I try to post something new, the AWS config wouldn't have the proper endpoint. For example, if you read my AWS configure to get the signed aws url, I don't update the endpoint; all I do is insert access and secret key.

I've updated it so that @ getSignedUrl, the AWS configure would be

```
AWS.configure.update({
    endpoint: "s3.amazonaws.com",
    accessKeyID: aws.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: aws.SECRET_KEY
});
```

Sorry to the people who tried to help. The context was impossible for you guys to help with my provided info, and I didn't think the index page would be causing the problem. I appreciate the advices.

Thanks.